# ng-repeat too powerful, need to dumb it down

Tags: angularjs, textarea, angularjs-ng-repeat

Newbie here, trying to figure this out.

I have an object literal that i want to have filtered down and shown in a textarea.

This fiddle shows what I want to achieve
http://jsfiddle.net/DrmVC/3/

```
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', age:25}, {name:'Mary', age:28}]">
I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
  </li>
</ul>
  <textarea> [1] John who is 25 years old.
[2] Mary who is 28 years old. </textarea>

</div>
</div>
```

Ng-repeat doesn't work for textareas. From my limited understanding, ng-repeat is instantiating new scope every time it repeats, while the textarea just wants some string to show -- how can i get it this string?

Maybe a working example of angularForeach filtering down an object literal (like ng-repeat does) and outputting to a string i can bind to like {{foreachStringOutput}}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do a ng-repeat inside a textbox?

Comment: Inside of a textarea. Textbox would probably be the same thing though, i imagine.

Comment: I just added an example, Your question wasn't entirely clear but I assume you were just trying to populate a value in the textbox based on the array which you would really want to do with the use of a controller to define the value.  Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are going to want to do is create a function to produce the text you want and bind that to your text area.  In the example below `friendText()` is looping over the array and producing the text.

Here is a quick demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/fmiSg3uJChy00bgffe9I?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.friends = [{name:'John', age:25}, {name:'Mary', age:28}];

  $scope.friendText = function() {
    var text ='';
    angular.forEach($scope.friends, function(value, key){
     text = text + '[' + (key+1) + '] ' + value.name + ' is ' + value.age + ' years old.'
    });

    return text;

  }

});
```

and the markup (the `ng-app` is defined at the html area and left off here but is on the demo link)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div>
    I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
      </li>
    </ul>
      <textarea> {{friendText()}}</textarea>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I might have confused a little by asking for a filtered ngrepeat, but didn't show that in the jsfiddle. Within the foreach I imagine I can use if statements to further define what I want to return as text. E.g. if i wanted only friends <26. Thanks again for your answer, I appreciate it very much :)